# Trying to implement Kendo Grid in angular but when i click on router link i am getitng this

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a  application using Kendo, which I was able to do using Kendo UI. Now I got a requirement to try the same using Angular with  Kendo UI. However I was stuck by following error.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sSGy.png)

My app module code goes like this.

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { OverlayModule } from "@angular/cdk/overlay";
import { AppRoutingModule, `ArrayOfComponents` } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { dataReaducer } from './shared/ngrx/e-commerce/shop.reducers';
import { MaterialModuleModule } from './materialModule/material-module/material-module.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { NgxSliderModule } from 'ngx-slider-v2';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthorizeInterceptor } from 'src/app/authentication/authorize.interceptor';
import { AuthorizeService } from './authentication/authorize.service';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
@NgModule({
  declarations:[
    AppComponent, ArrayOfComponents
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    OverlayModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ data: dataReaducer }),
    ToastrModule.forRoot({}),
    MaterialModuleModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    NgxSliderModule,
    GridModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthorizeService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthorizeInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }`
```

when I copy same URL and enter in new tab this is working.
can anyone help me to find out what is the problem here.